# How to get the physical_name of the secondary log shipping databases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The following query returns `M:\data\db.mdf` and `L:\data\db.log`. However, the server even doesn't have drive M: and L:.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_files
```

How to get the physical names of the disk files? I need to detach the database and make a copy of the database files to restore it on another machine since the secondary logshipping database cannot be backed up. What's the best way to make a copy of secondary db?